# Drop user cascade in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to drop a specific user (which may have active sessions) from the batch *without any user interaction*. I don't care about active sessions and want them to be dropped and rolled back. For Microsoft SQL i would do similar task with a single line:

```
osql -E -S localhost -b -Q "use master if ((select name from sysdatabases where name='%DB%') is not null) begin alter database [%DB%] set single_user with rollback immediate drop database [%DB%] end"
```

How do i do it for Oracle (10g XE on Windows)?

My current batch is:

```
sqlplus sys/*** as SYSDBA  @delete1.sql >delete.log
sqlplus sys/***@XE as SYSDBA  @delete2.sql >>delete.log
```

where delete1.sql:

```
startup force;
exit;
```

and delete2.sql:

```
drop user MYUSER cascade;
exit;
```

This is ugly as hell and takes too long comparing to the split second of MSSQL solution.

Comment: In Oracle a user has a schema so there's a lot more involved in dropping the user, especially if there are a lot of objects owned by it. Consider doing an ALTER USER ... ACCOUNT LOCK and then dropping it later at a more convenient time.

Comment: How often do you need to drop a user - why is its performance an issue?

Comment: This is part of my CI process (build -> recreate the db schema -> run integration tests) so it's executed almost on every commit. I can live with its performance but i'm shocked Oracle doesn't have means for this. I'm not asking something special, am i?

Comment: The reason i need to do "hard reset" is that sometimes the tests fail leaving active connections. I don't care of them on the build server so want them dropped.

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/trouble-killing-sessions-then-immediately-dropping-users-in-oracle-11g-xe for additional answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you use the following script (here named `drop_user_with_active_sessions.sql`):

```
set verify off

begin

  for s in (
    select 
      sid, serial#
    from
      v$session
    where 
      username = '&1'
  ) loop

    execute immediate 
       'alter system kill session ''' || 
        s.sid     || ',' ||
        s.serial# || ''' immediate';

  end loop;

  execute immediate 'drop user &1';

end;
/

exit
```

And the use it with

```
sqlplus username/password@instance @c:\path\to\drop_user_with_active_session.sql MYUSER
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
ORA-06512: at line 19

Answer (score 0):

you can do [Oracle SQL via the command prompt](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#BJECGGFH) and then do your [cascade drop user](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/drop_user.html).

I would recommend creating a sql script and [executing it from the command line](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA).

then you can wrap up command line text in your cmd/batch file.

but if you would like Oracle to handle the entire process I would recommend looking into the [job/schedule environment](http://www.oradev.com/dbms_scheduler.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "alter system kill session" mentioned above I've also needed to preface the kill session with something like:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION ''' ||
    to_char(s.sid) || ', ' || to_char(s.serial#) || ''' IMMEDIATE'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very, very bad idea to take a construct from one Database platform and assume I can run the exact same thing on a different platform. For example. Oracle has Create OR REPLACE procedure. MSSS isn't quite so simple. MSSS you can make a "temp" table with #name, in Oracle we use DDL. While dropping a user to recreate a fresh environment may have been the simplest approach on MSSS, perhaps there's a more Oracle-centric way to accomplish the same thing. It's a very good idea to ask for help on how to accomplish a task instead of why your way isn't working.

First, does the app being tested do DDL? to the tables and other objects?

If it only changes data, they way Oracle prefers apps to work, then why do you have to recreate all the objects. You just need to get the data back to the starting point.

Have you looked into Flashback Database? You should be able to create a restore point... do whatever you want and then flashback the database to that point in time.

Comment: I'm not Oracle expert and only have the working (for me) solution i described. I consider it ugly and wondering if there is a better one ('cause it is on other DBMS - SQL server as example).

Comment: I wish I knew why this wasn't a good answer. Flashback Database would be much easier than dropping and recreating everything.